# How do I add a Windows Live account to Empathy?

Tags: 10.04, empathy

I have a Windows Live account that I want to add to Empathy for messaging at work.  I use my work email as my login.  Nothing I try will get Empathy to connect.  I have already removed telepathy butterfly plugin, still nothing. What are the setting for adding Windows Live account?

Empathy 2.30.3

Comment: Is your problem with understanding the process to add your Windows Live account? Or is it, instead, a problem with _getting it to work_ (e.g., an error message, etc.)?

Comment: Getting it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding it through the "MSN" option with your username being "user@live.com".

Screenshot:

[image: Empathy Screnshot]

Comment: Exactly. When it comes to instant messaging, _Windows Live_ is simply a rebranding of _MSN_.

Comment: Yes. Sometimes things aren't obvious.  Good luck, OP, with getting this working.

Comment: Still not working.  That was how I tried in the first place.  Perhaps it is because I use my work email for my windows Live ID?  Does anyone have this working with a non hotmail/live email address?

Comment: @Andrew: I originally thought this was your problem, too, but then I thought of something else; I've posted an answer with a guess at what's happening.

Comment: Can you log in at the MSN website with your work email?

Answer (score 1):

If you've already tried the MSN protocol without success, it could be that your Windows Live password is extra-long.

I recently changed my account's password to a longer one, and non-Microsoft services such as Empathy and GMail could no longer log in. Once I brought the password back down to the original length, the other services were fine.

Shortening your password may solve the problem, but you'll have to decide for yourself whether or not you are comfortable with the decrease in security that would come as a result.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that at all.  That's a good point.

Comment: @gamerchick: Thanks! When I had the problem, I didn't see anything in help on Hotmail or GMail. Recognizing the issue on IM was what gave me the idea it was my password, so I never did check Microsoft's support info for Windows Live Messenger. I wonder if many people know about the issue at all.

Comment: That's a good point as I tend to choose very long passwords, but I changed the password, and still nothing.  @gamerchick02 I can log in.

Comment: @Andrew How short was the new password?

Comment: @Firefeather only 10 characters

Comment: @Andrew That's shorter than my old password's length, so I'd be surprised if this is your issue.